# Is there any way to customize the Google Reader interface?

Tags: google-reader

I'm using a netbook, with screen resolution of 1024x600. Surfing the web is generally okay, but the scrolling pane in Google Reader is rather small. Even when showing collapsed items, there's only about 7 visible at a time.

Is there any option to adjust the Reader interface to maximize use of vertical space?

I'm using Firefox on Windows 7, if it matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Google reader, hit the "F" key to put reader in full screen mode.

See [this link](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69973) for all of the keyboard shortcuts, or press "?" in Google Reader to show a quick screen of available keyboard shortcuts (Thanks [Lipis](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/408/lipis)).

Comment: or simply press "?".

Comment: @Lipis - Yes, pressing the "?" key in Google Reader will also show you the keyboard shortcuts - Thanks!  (I'll edit my post to reflect this)

Comment: I did not know Reader had such functionality! The "F" shortcut dramatically expands the viewing space for feed items. Thanks!

Comment: Combined with F11 to remove your browser chrome, you get a lot of space for your RSS reading. (It's something I do rather often.)

Answer (score 5):

You could always press `F11` to maximize the browser to full screen, that will so a few more items...Also, to go back and forth in a browser, press `Alt + right arrow` and `Alt + left arrow`